# Film where colour fades throughout to represent dying protagonist

Tags: identify-this-movie, film-techniques

Ok, I can usually find things using Google but no luck this time!

This is a film from around mid-90s I think, but could be +/- 10 years.

Male lead, who I think gets a kind of lethal injection which has so long to take effect. Or it may be a disease which is killing him.

But either way - he has a few hours to achieve his objective.

One of the defining things is that **as he gets weaker/the film progresses - the colour fades** - so towards the end of the film it is more black and white than colour.

Comment: Sounds almost a bit like crank but the colour element throws it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is *[D.O.A.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094933/)* from 1988 starring Dennis Quaid.

In the film (which starts out as black and white in homage to the original), Quaid has been poisoned and attempts to discover his killer before time runs out. As the film progresses the color is drained from the scenes until the film finishes in the black and white state of the opening.

Comment: Thanks! I did actually stumble upon the original D.O.A. whilst trying to find this...

Comment: I actually have a soft spot for this film. I was a big fan of Annabel Jankel and Rocky Morton (the directors) after their creation of Max Headroom and some superb 80's music videos, but they dropped the ball with their attempt at a Super Mario Bros movie.

Comment: I've never actually seen it I just remember reading about it once. The Mario Bros one sounds like a horrible idea.